# jQuery arrange sortable , arrange by ID's

Tags: jquery, list, jquery-ui-sortable

This the html structure.i have made the li sortable with jquery. but want the list with id= `type1` stick together always and `type2` be separate. And `type2` should not be movable inside lists with is `type1`

```
 <div id="container" class="container">
      <li id="type1" class="type1">Option 1<li>
      <li id="type1" class="type1">Option 2<li>
      <li id="type1" class="type1">Option 3<li>
      <li id="type1" class="type1">Option 4<li>
      <li id="type2" class="type2">Option 5<li>
      <li id="type2" class="type2">Option 6<li>
    </div>
```

I am confused how can i achieve this with jQuery.  pls help .thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to solve your problem using jQuery UI. Below is the code. Hope it helps.

```js
$('container').sortable()
$('.container-type').sortable()
```

```css
.type1, .type2{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" class="container">
  <ul class="container-type">
    <li id="type1" class="type1">Option 1</li>
    <li id="type1" class="type1">Option 2</li>
    <li id="type1" class="type1">Option 3</li>
    <li id="type1" class="type1">Option 4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="container-type">
    <li id="type2" class="type2">Option 5</li>
    <li id="type2" class="type2">Option 6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks...actually i am getting the list out of a php code( wordpress query) so i wont get an html structure as yours it will be a continues list.is it possible to achieve this without the ul separation ? Is it possible to have a option 5 and option 6 to be placed above others(1,2,3,4)

Comment: Can you differentiate in the list what will be type1 and type2? If you can update the list that you get maybe I can find a solution.

Comment: i modified it like above and now it works fine ..thanks